# How can I convert code from version #2 to version #4 of pine script?

Tags: pine-script

I have the code for a pine script program in version 2, but I need to convert this to version 4 so that it'll be the same version as the rest of my program. Please help me out if you can.

```
length = input(50)
MEA  = close
ERRmea = abs(nz(EST[length],MEA[1]) - MEA)
ERRprv = abs(change(MEA)*-1)
KG = nz(ERR[1],ERRprv)/(nz(ERR[1],ERRprv) + ERRmea)
EST = nz(EST[1],MEA[1]) + KG * (MEA - nz(EST[1],MEA[1]))
ERR = (1 - KG) * ERRprv
plot(EST,color=red,transp=0)
```

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem.

Comment: This code is in version 2 of pine script, but I need to convert it to version 4 because the rest of my code uses 1d arrays, a feature only available in version 4.